# How to change end-of-line conventions?

Tags: python, pandas, newline, python-2.x, lf

I have what I thought would be a simple task. I need to create a text file that has uses the unix LF convention at the end of a line. However, when I attempt to accomplish this using pandas .to_csv, I end up with CR LF. This wouldn't be a problem if I were staying on my machine and if I were using python for everything. But I am not. The code will be part of an app that a coworker will be using, and the file is being sent to a third party for automation. The code is as follows:

```
df.to_csv("filename.txt", sep = '\t',line_terminator = '\n')
```

This sits in the middle of my code, but it always switches back to CR LF when the files is saved in the target folder. I think it may be something to do with Windows being "[helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535922/c-change-newline-from-crlf-to-lf)". I have tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422107/how-to-convert-crlf-to-lf-on-a-windows-machine-in-python#36422321) type of solution with no luck. I am also not having any luck finding a [dos2unix](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux) type package for Python. Is there anyway that I can write lines that end in '\n' and have it stick in Windows (using to_csv if possible)?

I am using Python 2.7 and Windows 7.

Edit: I know about notepad++, but I am trying to write this all in Python, so my coworker only has to click a button (I will be using Tkinter and freezing this to an .exe once I am finished). The .txt can be Windows formatted, but I will be (am) writing the same information to a .MAT and .ref file. In those files it needs the '\n' end of line, but Windows is still giving me '\r\n'.

Comment: I suggest you try to write the filename without an extension that is familiar to Windows (.txt) maybe just not have an extension. It doesn't matter to linux anyways.

Comment: @SaherAhwal: the file extension has nothing to do with the problem, the problem is with the data _in_ the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note this answer is specific to Python 2's CSV handling.

`to_csv` defaults to opening the file in `'w'` mode which defaults to text mode.  On Windows text mode translates `\n` to `\r\n`.  Open the the file in binary mode instead, and specify an encoding if you have non-ASCII text in your frame.

```
df.to_csv('filename.txt',sep='\t',mode='wb',encoding='utf8')
```